# Which broker parameters can be dynamically modified in kafka1.0.0?

Tags: apache-kafka

The Kafka version used in my production environment is 1.0.0. According to the information learned from the official website, it seems that Kafka before version 1.1.0 does not support dynamic modification of most parameters, but I still want to know which specific Parameters are dynamically modified.
If my parameters cannot be modified dynamically, what method should be used to restart and modify the parameters so that I can minimize the impact of the external service?

Answer (score 0):

For Kafka 1.1.0, the following parameters can be updated dynamically.

**Broker Config** -

http://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation.html#dynamicbrokerconfigs

**Example**

> bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type brokers --entity-name 0 --alter --add-config log.cleaner.threads=2

**Topic Config** -

http://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation.html#topicconfigs

You can change the topic configuration using the `alter` command as given below.

**Example**

```
> bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name my-topic
    --alter --add-config max.message.bytes=128000
```